# Azure load balancing configuration with App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

**What am I trying to do**

I have to azure apps deployed as App services. To make rest post easy let's call them "blog" and "landing_page". Both of them are hosted, so they URL are blog.azurewebsites.net and landing_page.azurewebsites.net.
I want to configure "something" in Azure with following rules:

- if user access http://mydomain/ - content of landing_page.azurewebsites.net
- if user access http://mydomain/blog - content of blog.azurewebsites.net

**What I tried**

After reading documentation, I have to reject Traffic Manager because it works on DNS level. From the other two I decided to use Application Gateway, because it should work on eny Endpoint (Any Azure internal IP address, public internet IP address, Azure VM, or Azure Cloud Service).
I configured my Application Gateway setting backend to: landing_page.azurewebsites.net. But in "Backend health" the app status is unhealthy. I tried also:

- blog.azurewebsites.net - unhealthy
- www.wp.pl (polish news portal) - is working
- gazeta.pl (polish news portal) - is working
- stapp.space (my blog) - this is same as piotrstapp.azurewebsites.net and status is unhealthy

**Question :)**

What did I wrong? Maybe should I use something else on Azure? Or am I missing something?

Comment: do you have a domain or you have plans to use .azurewebsites.net ? It would be much easier if you could by one domain, then it would be just DNS settings

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I have my domain and I'm planning to use it.

Comment: Then you can use Azure DNS and just create CNAMEs to both apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio i cannot use CNAME because CNAME doesnt support URL paths. Only domain names. As I wrote I'm trying to redirect URL path

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that custom probes is turned on and configured in the HTTP settings of the WAF for your site. If you don't the Application Gateway will try to go to the IP of the App Service Environment without passing a Host header, which won't work and will throw the probe into an unhealthy state resulting in a "502 Gateway Proxy" error.

[There is a great article here](http://sabbour.me/how-to-run-an-app-service-behind-a-waf-enabled-application-gateway/)

Comment: Do I have to install App Service Environment ?

Comment: I believe so, unfortunately it's a premium service.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Azure's application gateway path-based rules function:
[Create a path-based rule for an application gateway by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal)

[image: path-based rules diagram]

Comment: It should if you have app service for landing_page.azurewebsites.net and another app service for blog.azurewebsites.net. You may need to configure custom health probes otherwise the app gateway uses "127.0.0.1" as the host header. Check out more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal